# Java can't find class in same package when I run Main from command line

Tags: java

I moved a class from Main.java into their own .java files and now the IDE (IntelliJ) can't find them, even though they are in the same package. Here are the first lines of Main...

```
package readability;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var filePath = args[0];
        var textAnalyser = new TextAnalyser(filePath);
```

... and here's the error I get when I run it from the command line:

```
C:\Users\123md\IdeaProjects\Readability Score\Readability Score\task\src\readability>java Main.java in.txt
Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        var textAnalyser = new TextAnalyser(filePath);
                               ^
  symbol:   class TextAnalyser
  location: class Main
```

Interestingly, when I just say `String filePath = "in.txt"` and run it in the console, it does find the class and runs fine, so why can't it find the class when I run it from the command line? Thanks!

Comment: Do you run the code directly from command line or define the cmd parameters through intellij?

Comment: You probably need to import `TextAnalyser` class

Comment: You can click Alt+Enter (or Option+Enter), and IntelliJ will show a dialog box where you can chose "Import class..." and it will import it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can only run single `*.java` file with `java` command. If your program uses mutiple files, you have to compile it first:

```
javac readability/Main.java readability/TextAnalyser.java
```

and then run:

```
java readability.Main in.txt
```

For more info see: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Comment: The javac command works (I actually did javac *.java as I have another class as well), but when I do ``` java readability.Main in.txt ``` I get...
```
Error: Could not find or load main class readability.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: readability.Main
```
Any ideas please?

Comment: Obviously, it can't find the class but why not? When I do "java Main in.txt" I get a different message: 
``` Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: readability/Main (wrong name: Main) ``` Any ideas please?

Comment: Go to parent directory and use fully qualified class name: `java readability.Main readability/in.txt`

Comment: That didn't work either, but it did work when I removed the "package readability" statement from all classes and just did "java Main.java in.txt". I guess I have somehow failed to create the package in the first place. I will have to read up more on packages, but any tips much appreciated